# Convert image to thumbnail and maintain aspect ratio

Tags: java, image, thumbnails

I want to convert large images into thumbnails but also want to maintain the aspect ratio. In [this link](http://get2java.blogspot.in/search/label/Aspect%20Ratio) they convert the images into thumbnails but they use `JPEGCodec` and `JPEGImageEncoder` classes, which I think are deprecated.

Oracle provide some [new library](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7380-JAI-1.1.1_01-oth-JPR) to deal with images. So how to convert images into thumbnail using new libraries?

Comment: *"Oracle provide some new library"*  That is JAI.  It would only require the info. in  the link of @MadProgrammer with `javax.imageio.ImageIO` to load and save the image, ..unless you mean for TIFF - then use JAI (that supports more formats). ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm sure your aware that that's a `ImageIO` plugin for TIFF from the `JAI` project ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I am now!  Thanks for the heads-up.. :)

Comment: i found the solution in this [link](http://harmeetsingh13.blogspot.in/2013/05/create-images-into-thumbnails-and.html)